# React + immutableJS renders some weird output in old browsers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

In some of the not latest browsers my ReactJS website outputs weird ids, which look like internals of immutableJS objects
Here is a rendering in IE10:

[image: react weird rendering]

In Chrome & Firefox everything looks good.
Here is the code that renders that first snippet:

`const winner = this.props.worldviews.sort((a, b) => a.get('voteCount') < b.get('voteCount')).slice(0, 1).map(worldview => {
      return (
        <p>{worldview.get('title')}: {worldview.get('voteCount')} <i className='icon-check'></i></p>
      );
    });`

`this.props.worldviews` is a List of immutableJS objects.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @DominicTobias in this exact case there's only one item (see `slice(0,1)`), that's why. In other lists I do use a key, but it doesn't help. Converting from ImmutableJS into normal array does help though, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved if I call `.toArray()` on results of map like this:

`const winner = this.props.worldviews.sort((a, b) => a.get('voteCount') < b.get('voteCount')).slice(0, 1).map(worldview => {
      return (
        <p>{worldview.get('title')}: {worldview.get('voteCount')} <i className='icon-check'></i></p>
      );
    }).toArray();`

This should have not been a problem, as I'm using React 0.13 which supports any ierators, but apparently on older browsers it breaks.

Comment: If you don't provide a key then React will try and get the index, except it seems to be having a hard time getting the index from that custom immutable structure. As Alexander said you could give it a key if there's something unique on the worldview object like an id. (when you do toArray then react knows how to get the index)